# How can I show toast message on Activity with multi Fragments?

Tags: android

I am using Navigation Drawer for Fragments with 3 tabs

```
FirstFragment.class 

SecondFragment.class

ThirdFragment.class
```

Main Activity starting with `FirstFragment` When i opened 'SecondFragment' Toast Message not working this Fragment. I want toast message events working to `SecondFragment`.

How do I make it? Any suggestions?

ToastMessage

```
@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getActivity(),
                            parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + " Selected" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

Comment: could you post your code

Comment: Can you expatiate, didn't quite get the question?

Comment: This is example toast message show open first fragment but i need opens other fragments..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Toast** it´s ***not Context sensitive.*** It doesn't know if you're still on the FirstFragment or you are now on the SecondFragment, you're still on the same Activity. The same would happen if you call another Activity.

I recommend you to use this nice library called **Crouton**

> https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton

You can create 3 default message types like ALERT, INFO or CONFIRM. You can also create your custom messages.

```
Crouton.makeText(getActivity(), "Hi there!", Style.INFO).show();
```

Then on you onDestroy method just call

```
Crouton.cancelAllCroutons();
```

Easy pie.

Hope it helps!